# How do I figure out maxima and minima after getting the condition relating partial derivatives using Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem states: Use Lagrange multipliers to find the absolute minimum and maximum values of the function $f(x,y)=x^2y$ subject to the constraint $3x^2 + 2y^2 = 4$.

My attempt at a solution:

I am using Lagrange multipliers and obtain these equations. These are the equations.
$$f_x=\lambda g_x$$ $$f_y=\lambda g_y $$ $$g(x,y)=4$$ $$f_x=2xy$$ $$g_x=6x$$
$$f_y = x^2$$ $$g_y = 4y$$ $$g(x,y)=3x^2+2y^2$$

Plugging in the equations and coming up with a system of three equations and three unknowns yields.
$$2xy=\lambda 6x$$ $$x^2=\lambda 4y$$ $$3x^2+2y^2=4$$

I cannot figure out how to take it further to find the absolute maximum and minimums.

Comment: Langrange $\to$ Lagrange

Comment: Was my answer helpful or did I miss something?

Comment: Very helpful. You did not miss anything. Helped me out thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations you arrived at are:

$$ 2xy = \lambda 6 x$$

And,

$$ x^2 = \lambda 4y$$

Considering the first equation:

$$ x[ 2y - 6 \lambda ] = 0$$

So, either $ y= 3 \lambda$ or $ x=0$

According to the second equation, if $ x=0$ then $ y=0$ but this doesn't satisfy the constraint so let's throw this solution away. Now if $ y= 3 \lambda$ then, $ x^2 = 12 \lambda^2$ and plugging this and $ y= 3 \lambda$ into constraint gives:

$$ 3( 12 \lambda^2) + 2(3 \lambda)^2=4$$

$$ 36 \lambda^2 + 18 \lambda^2 -4 =0$$

And,

$$ y= 3 \lambda$$

$$ x^2 = 3 \lambda^2$$

Now, you have two $\lambda$ from the quadratic and each corresponds to an $ x-y$ minima/maxima. To check which if maxima or minima, you'll have to plug it into the function. ( I think you could use hessian here to identify maxima and minima but I don't understand that concept enough to explain).

**Tl;dr**  : Plug result of lagrange multipliers into the constraint equation

Answer (score 0):

The function $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ x^2y \ $ is symmetric about the $ \ y-$ axis, but has an *anti*-symmetry about the $ \ x-$ axis [ $ \ f(x,-y) \ = \ -f(x,y) \ $ ] and is positive for $ \ y \ > \ 0 \ $ . Since the constraint equation represents an ellipse centered on the origin, we should expect there to be four critical points placed symmetrically then, one in each quadrant. Because of the anti-symmetry of the function, the two maxima will occur in the first and second quadrant, while the third and fourth quadrants contain the two minima.  So this can be determined before any calculation is made.

The work by **Buraian** confirms the presence of the four critical points, in that $ \ x^2 \ = \ 12 \lambda^2 \ $ and $ \ y^2 \ = \ 9 \lambda^2 \ $ .  We have

$$ 54 \ \lambda^2 \ \ = \ \ 4  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{27} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{24}{27} \ \ = \ \ \frac{8}{9} \ \ , \ \ y^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{3} \ \ . $$

The **absolute maxima**  are thus located at $ \  \left( \ \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3} \ , \ \ \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \ \right) $ with   $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ + \frac{8}{9} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \ $  and the **absolute minima** are at $ \  \left( \ \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3} \ , \ \ -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \ \right) $ with   $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ - \frac{8}{9} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \ \ . $